# install Norwegian Internet explorer 8 on English windows 7

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, language-pack

I have a computer with Windows 7, 32 bit English version and IE8 English version. I need to have a computer with Windows 7 English and IE8 Norwegian version. My computer is not connected to the Internet, so I can't update windows 7 with the Norwegian language pack.

On the Microsoft download site, I can download almost every other version of IE with Norwegian language , but not IE8 for windows 7, 32 bit.

My question is, where can I download IE8 Norwegian full version for windows 7, 32 bit.

Any thoughts or workarounds is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can download for Windows Vista and install it. It will run work without any problem.

Comment: I have tried this, but I get the message: "Internet Explorer 8 is not supportet by this Operation System"(translated from norwegian). Maybe this is because I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise edition, which edition of windows 7 have you tried this on?

Comment: I think they have end up the IE8 with Vista so due to that they are not showing it up there in the list, you can download [IE9 in Norwegian language](http://view.atdmt.com/action/mrtiex_FY12IE9StaPrdIE9WWpageforVistaWin7FNL_1?href=http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/D/9/7D9CA697-1206-425F-8252-8AE7AFE9E721/IE9-Windows7-x86-nor.exe) for Windows 7 32 bit. Or see the full [link here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/internet-explorer/downloads/ie-9/worldwide-languages)